# Paredit: paredit-forward and paredit-backward don't work

Tags: key-bindings, balanced-parentheses

I've been having trouble with navigating in [`paredit`](http://melpa.org/#/paredit). When I try using `C-M-f` and `C-M-b` to go forward and backward, nothing happens. The minibuffer doesn't respond and the point doesn't move.

When I type `C-h f paredit-forward/backward` it confirms that the function is bound to the keys mentioned above, and when I type `C-h m` in a buffer with `paredit-mode` enabled it shows the same binding. Other `paredit` functionality works just fine - I'm slurping and barfing all over the place.

I'm beginning to suspect it's a problem with the `C-M` combination. When I try to use `C-h k` to identify the combination, nothing registers.

I use Emacs on Windows 7 and Bodhi Linux (a Ubuntu derivative), and I see the same (lack of) behavior on both. Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: Here's an idea: could you try running `emacs -Q` and pressing `C-h k C-M-f` in the `*scratch*` buffer? (`C-M-f` is bound to `forward-sexp` by default.) If this does not tell you "C-M-f runs the command forward-sexp...", then `paredit` is not to blame.

Comment: I did as you said and it does say "C-M-f runs the command forward-sexp, which is an interactive compiled
Lisp function."

Comment: What about `M-x paredit-forward`?  What about `C-h k C-M-f`

Comment: Also, +1 for the sentence "I'm slurping and barfing all over the place. " alone. ;-)

Comment: I don't know what the situation is under Windows, but Under Linux C-M sometimes gets grabbed by the window manager instead of by emacs.  Have you tried rebinding the function to another key combination?

Comment: Ah, and you can also try `ESC C-f`.

Comment: Do you have the same problem if you run `emacs -q` and enable paredit? Dually, do you have the same problem if you comment out the references to `paredit` in your `.emacs`, but leave the rest alone? If you press `C-M-f` then `C-h l`, what are the last few keys that appear in the `*Help*` window? Do other `C-M-letter` combinations show the same problem?